# Why are functions getKey, getValue and setValue not associated with Map?

Tags: java

As per Effective Java, Item 22,

> Many Map implementations have an internal Entry object for each key-value pair in the map. 
>   While each entry is associated with a map, the methods on an entry
>   (getKey, getValue, and setValue) do not need access to the map.

Can you explain what it means?  Can you give an example of a typical Map implementation to show how these functions aren't dependent on Map internals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is java.util.HashMap.Entry implementation

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        final K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K,V> next;
        final int hash;

        ...

        public final K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public final V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public final V setValue(V newValue) {
            V oldValue = value;
            value = newValue;
            return oldValue;
        }
        ...
```

as you can see getKey, getValue, and setValue work only with Entry's fields and do not need access to HashMap itself.

But HashMap of course needs access to its entries, so it holds them in a field as an array

```
public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable {
    ...
    Entry[] table;
    ...
```

Comment: Can you also explain the relationship between Entry<K, V> and Map<K, V>?

Answer (score 0):

Map consists of many `Entry` objects. You can think of Entry as a key-value pair.

It is Map contains entries and entry does not have any access to the Map.

Entry has access to its own fields but not to other entries in the hashmap i.e. entry can provide getters and setters to its own contained fields and doesn't have any access to HashMap.